# Will i never get a visa because i lied to USA embassy

Tags: visa-refusals

I told I had an accident, which did not happen and later confessed the truth. I was denied and after I applied again and was denied again. What should I do? Will I ever get a visa to U.S.

Comment: How long did you stay in the US after you fell out of status? How old were you?

Comment: I am over 18. i was very stressed when i found out i was illegal for 8 months.

Comment: How long ago was this?

Comment: last month.  i am banned from usa forever right?

Comment: What was the reason given for the visa refusal? US visa refusals always cite a specific section of US law. By this we may be able to know whether a ban was applied to you.

Comment: I was given 214b

Answer (score 6):

Your overstay for a period of 8 months will give you an automatic 3 year ban from entering the US.  Whilst this ban can be reduced/removed, realistically that's incredibly rare and would require a very good reason which you seemingly don't have.

Unfortunately by lying to the consular staff you have likely made your situation far worse.  In general, making false claims during an interview is fraud, and committing fraud during a visa application leaves you ineligible to enter the US. In some situations Ineligibility can be overturned (via a Waiver of Ineligible, which is a process that only the consulate staff can initiate and takes at least about 6 months to complete), but generally this won't be possible until a suitable time has passed since the incident.

It's not possible to know what details the consulate staff recorded against your application, but presuming they did record your lie then realistically it's very unlikely you will be give a new visa for a very long time, if ever - and even that's only after the 3 years of your ban where the chances are zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic rule, but you should expect to have a *ten year ban*.
After that, you are able to apply for a visa, and you would need to make a convincing argument at you would not overstay again.

Comment: Ten year ban? Where did you get that from?